# meaning of the phrase "for if"?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/8LAeWF1GDYc). It is at around 7 minute and 15 second. Here is the context:

> **For if** a sustainable source of water could be found, it could lead to colonazation on a simpler and grander scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**for** there can be paraphrased as "because".

> Don't make your frying pan too hot. For if you do, you may overcook the fish.

Comment: +1.  We should note that this use of **for** is somewhat old-fashioned and poetic today.  ([Use of "for if" has been decreasing for about 200 years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+if&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20if%3B%2Cc0), and similar patterns hold for "for should" and "for had".)

Comment: @stangdon: I do think there is an overall decline but I would not go as far you do in calling it old-fashioned and poetic. The decline is patchy, and in some places you hear it more often than in others, and there are plenty of attestations in non-literary texts from the 21st century.